# How can I model a json data which is inconsistent in nature

Tags: json, model

Use Case:
I need to store questions feed in JSON format. Each question can be of type - MCQ, Open Ended, Coding, TRUE/FALSE
For MCQ, the object should contain possible options, no. of options; whereas for others, it is not the case.

How can I design it consistent? (So that I will have same keys in each object)